# Third Normal Form and Boyce Code normal form

Tags: databases

I know that this is not a question answer site but for sake of explaining my doubt I have to post the entire question..

> Consider the following statements.
>
> ```
> If relation R is in 3NF and every key is simple, then R is in BCNF
> If relation R is in 3NF and R has only one key, then R is in BCNF
>
> Both 1 and 2 are true
> 1 is true but 2 is false
> 1 is false and 2 is true
> Both 1 and 2 are false
> ```

---

Ans given is $a$, but how can it be so?

I agree with the first statement but for the second one consider that we have a relation $R={\{A,B,C,D\}}$ where $AB$ is the key, and say $C->B$ then it satisfies $3nf$ right? But  it is $NOT$ in $BCNF$ right? as here we have $non-prime$  $deriving$  $a$  $prime$  $attribute$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $S_1:$ If relation R is in 3NF and every key is simple, then R is in
> BCNF.
>
> $S_2:$ If relation R is in 3NF and R has only one key, then R is in BCNF

Both statements are correct.

**Your counterexample is as follow:**

$R(A,B,C,D)$ where fds that hold are $FD = \{AB \rightarrow CD, C\rightarrow B\}$.

Now, this example does not satisfy premice of any of the statement because there are two candidate keys i.e $\{AB\}, \{AC\}$.

Comment: Thanks brother.. :)